# NodeJS discord-rpc application not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to setup Discord RPC. For it, I registered a new application and copied the client ID.
Then I am using this code:

```
const RPC = require("discord-rpc");
const discordClient = new RPC.Client({ transport: "ipc" });

let defaultActivity;

(async () => {
    discordClient.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log('Authed for user', discordClient.user);
    console.log(discordClient.application.name);
    console.log(discordClient.user.username);

    defaultActivity = {
        details: `${discordClient.user.username}`,
        state: "Test",
        largeImageKey: "test",
        largeImageText: "Kirka Client",
        smallImageText: `${discordClient.user.username}#${discordClient.user.discriminator}`,
    }

    discordClient.setActivity(defaultActivity);
    });
await discordClient.login({clientId: "871730144836976650"}).catch(console.error)
})();
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Authed for user { id: '771601176155783198',
username: 'AwesomeSam',
discriminator: '7985',
avatar: '93d3fd4fb9fd0921830d69e07a248036',
bot: false,
flags: 176,
premium_type: 1 }
(node:6664) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
at RPCClient.discordClient.on (D:\kirkaclient\src\features\discordRPC.js:9:47)
at RPCClient.emit (events.js:198:13)
at RPCClient.login (D:\kirkaclient\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\client.js:139:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is as it says.

```
Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

It seems that the property "discordClient.application" in line 9 is null, so it could not read a "name" value of null.

I'm not into discord-rpc, I do prefer discord.js, so I can't come up with a solution for this. 
You should try debugging it with `console.log(discordClient)`